# Excel: Find exactly how closely two similar columns match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'd like to compare two columns which are somewhat similar and see exactly how similar(the overlap %) they are. My grid is about 600x600 but here's an abridged example.

```
        100 101 102 103 104 105
   A    1   1   1   1   1   1
   B    1   1   1   1   1   1
   C    1   1   1   1   1   1
   D        1       1   1   1
   E            1   1   1   
   F                        1
   G                        
   TTL  3   4   4   5   5   5
       100% 75% 75% 80% 80% 80%
```

We'll say these are cars and their parts. The area in the grid is a binary yes/no, 1/blank indicator. Cars #101 and #102 both have 4 parts, but between them only three are the same, so they are considered 75% similar. Cars #103 and 104 are exactly the same, but between all cars with 5 parts they are only 80% similar.

How would you go about getting these numbers with a large data set? There may be thirty "cars" with 600 "parts" in them which need to be compared. I have all data except for the percentages.

Comment: So you are only comparing against cars that have the same number of parts?  How would you compare 3 or 4 cars that have the same number of parts?

Comment: Ohh are you just wanting the total % of parts that are the same across all the cars with the same number of parts?

Comment: Chancea, your second comment is correct. So there may only be 1 car or 50 cars with a certain number of parts and, only within those cars, what percentage of parts used are used in each car in the subset. I'd repeat this for each part # total.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution. Create two named ranges:
1) models -- which refers to the header cells containing the numbers 100, 101, etc

2) parts -- which is the single column column of the cells along the left of your data containing the numbers A,B, . It is assumed that this is to the left of the grid containing the 1's

Say you have two cells, say F15 and G15 which contain numbers like 101 or 102
In some other cell -- enter the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(OFFSET(parts,0,MATCH(F15,models)),OFFSET(parts,0,MATCH(G15,models)))/SUM(OFFSET(parts,0,MATCH(G15,models)))
```

this should compute the number of rows in the two columns specified by the values in F15 and G15 which are both 1, divided by the number of 1's in the second column.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I may have layed out too much info in my first question. I suppose the real meat of it is:
If I have a square range, how would I count the number of occurrances where a row in that square range sums to a certain number. With the chart above, how would I say, "My range is E2:G8, how many of these rows total 3?" The answer should be 3. From there I can get my result with other formulas.

Comment: @bobh2os That's the easy part I thought... just a simple `COUNTIF`

Comment: Hmm...maybe I'm doing something wrong in my formula. My total range in this example would be E2:G8, the condition to count would be sum(E2:G2)=3, sum(E3:G3)=8, ..., sum(E8:G8)=3. I guess I'm having clarifying in the condition it needs to sum entire rows before counting or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy with a helper row like 'TTL' in your example, just use SUMIF:

`=SUMIF(**TTLRange**, 3)`

You just need to replace **TTLRange** with the cells that contain your totals.

**EDIT:**

You could add a helper column after each existing column, using the data in the example, this column could contain:

`=IF(A1<>"", A1=C1, FALSE)`

Then in another helper row, below your TTL row, add the following:

`=SUMPRODUCT((B1:B7=TRUE)*1)/C8`

Comment: I still don't get how the OP is going to make those percents happen even with that helper row (without VBA that is)

Comment: I agree without using VBA it would be too time consuming. OP could add a helper column after each existing column, using the data in the example, this column could contain: `=IF(A1<>"", A1=C1, FALSE)` then in another helper row, below the first, add the following `=SUMPRODUCT((B1:B7=TRUE)*1)/C8`

Comment: I don't get how that compares more than 2 Car's

Comment: In the sample data the OP only appears to be comparing adjacent columns.

Comment: Look at cars 103, 104, and 105 (and then I asked about this in the comments)

Comment: My bad. Time to retire for the evening!

Comment: I feel you.  I tried this with a bunch of different array/sumproduct combos and haven't really gotten anywhere

Answer (score 0):

The data in this answer is assumed to be in this format:

```
         A          B    C   D   E   F   G
    ---------------------------------------
 1|                 100 101 102 103 104 105
 2| A               1   1   1   1   1   1
 3| B               1   1   1   1   1   1
 4| C               1   1   1   1   1   1
 5| D                   1       1   1   1
 6| E                       1   1   1
 7| F                                   1
 8| G                   
 9| TTL             3   4   4   5   5   5
10| Similarity     100% 75% 75% 80% 80% 80%
```

This answer involves some heavy math and matrix manipulation.  I will explain this in-depth, but first here is the formula I used:

*Note this is an array formula entered with:* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

#### Formula:

```
=SUM((MMULT((IF($B$9:$G$9=B9,$B$2:$G$8,($A$2:$A$8>0)*1)),TRANSPOSE(($B$9:$G$9>0)*1))=COUNTA($B$9:$G$9))*1)/B9
```

---

Here are the steps (this is long):

#### Step 1

The point of this step is to create a matrix that contains only the cars with the same amount of parts.  All other cars will have a 1 for each part.  This matrix feeds into step #2.

To explain this step I will use cars 101 and 102 which both have 4 parts.  Using cars 101 and 102 we need to create this matrix from our raw data:

```
1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   0   1   1   1
1   0   1   1   1   1
1   0   0   1   1   1
1   0   0   1   1   1
```

This matrix contains a 1 for each part except the ones that cars 101 and 102 do not have.  This was achieved using the inner `IF` statement of the formula, but referencing either C9 or D9 for parts 101 or 102:

```
=IF($B$9:$G$9=C9,$B$2:$G$8,($A$2:$A$8>0)*1)
 or
=IF($B$9:$G$9=D9,$B$2:$G$8,($A$2:$A$8>0)*1)
```

The way this works is first it creates an array of true/false values for the IF statement to work with:

```
$B$9:$G$9=D9 => {FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE}
```

using this it determines to either look into $B$2:$G$8 (for true cases) or ($A$2:$A$8>0)*1 (for false cases).  Looking into $B$2:$G$8 will return the corresponding range for the car being looked at, in this case it will yield `$C$2:$C$8` and `$D$2:$D$8`.  For all false cases it will create an array of 1's the size of how many parts are listed in column A.  Since this example has 7 parts, this will yield `{1,1,1,1,1,1,1}` for each false case.  Putting all this together creates the new matrix.

---

#### Step 2

This step we need to create a sum for each row in the previous matrix.  To do this with matrix manipulation, we need to multiply that matrix by an array of 1's for *each* car (including those that have different amount of parts).

Continuing with our example of cars 101 and 102 we need to perform this:

```
1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 6
1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 6
1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 6
1 + 1 + 0 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 5
1 + 0 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 5
1 + 0 + 0 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 4
1 + 0 + 0 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 4
```

This is done with matrix multiplication:

```
 __                 __         _   _
|1   1   1   1   1   1|       |  1  |     1x1 + 1x1 + 1x1 + 1x1 + 1x1 + 1x1 = 6
|1   1   1   1   1   1|       |  1  |     1x1 + 1x1 + 1x1 + 1x1 + 1x1 + 1x1 = 6
|1   1   1   1   1   1|       |  1  |     1x1 + 1x1 + 1x1 + 1x1 + 1x1 + 1x1 = 6
|1   1   0   1   1   1|   X   |  1  | =>  1x1 + 1x1 + 0x1 + 1x1 + 1x1 + 1x1 = 5
|1   0   1   1   1   1|       |  1  |     1x1 + 0x1 + 1x1 + 1x1 + 1x1 + 1x1 = 5
|1   0   0   1   1   1|       |  1  |     1x1 + 0x1 + 0x1 + 1x1 + 1x1 + 1x1 = 4
|1   0   0   1   1   1|        ‾   ‾      1x1 + 0x1 + 0x1 + 1x1 + 1x1 + 1x1 = 4
 ‾‾                 ‾‾
```

Since we already have the first matrix, to create the single column of 1's we need to look at how many cars we have.  This is easily done by referencing either the car# range or the TTL range (as long as there are never any cars with 0 parts).  I used TTL in this example.  Simply call ($B$9:$G$9>0)*1 to get `{1,1,1,1,1,1}` which is a single *row*.  Then wrap it with a `TRANSPOSE` to make it one *column*.  Then use MMULT to multiply the two:

```
MMULT((IF($B$9:$G$9=B9,$B$2:$G$8,($A$2:$A$8>0)*1)),TRANSPOSE(($B$9:$G$9>0)*1))
```

---

#### Step 3

Now it starts to get fairly straight-forward.  We just need to count how many values within the single column matrix are equal to the maximum amount of cars.  To get the number of cars you can hard code this or just a `COUNTA` on either the TTL row: or the car# row.  Again I just used TTL:

```
COUNTA($B$9:$G$9)
```

Just use this conditional (with multiplying it by 1 to get 1's and 0's) within a SUM to get the total count:

```
SUM((MMULT(...)=COUNTA($B$9:$G$9))*1)
```

In this continued example that would look like:

```
6 =? 6 => 1
6 =? 6 => 1
6 =? 6 => 1
5 =? 6 => 0
5 =? 6 => 0
4 =? 6 => 0
4 =? 6 => 0
   SUM =  3
```

---

#### Step 4

The final and most simple: divide this count by the amount of parts for that car (TTL) to get the percentage.

```
SUM((MMULT(...)=COUNTA($B$9:$G$9))*1)/B9 = (3 / 4) = 0.75 => 75%
```

---

Here is a final screenshot for clarity:

[image: Final Output]

---

You of course will need to update your ranges based on your data.

For adding more cars change all horizontal ranges:

```
=SUM((MMULT((IF($B$9:$G$9=B9,$B$2:$G$8,($A$2:$A$8>0)*1)),TRANSPOSE(($B$9:$G$9>0)*1))=COUNTA($B$9:$G$9))*1)/B9
                ^^^^^^^^^    ^^   ^^                                ^^^^^^^^^                ^^   ^^
```

For adding more parts change all vertical ranges:

```
=SUM((MMULT((IF($B$9:$G$9=B9,$B$2:$G$8,($A$2:$A$8>0)*1)),TRANSPOSE(($B$9:$G$9>0)*1))=COUNTA($B$9:$G$9))*1)/B9
                  ^^   ^^  ^        ^^       ^^^^                     ^^   ^^                 ^^   ^^       ^
```